# Job Title Classification Training Data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

One of the tasks is to map Job Titles on LinkenIn and other data sources to more commonly known job titles so we can match better (e.g. Software Developer Engineer II --> Software Developer). I realize this is a very common problem and I have seen many papers on the different algorithms and prediction models to implement, but no link to training data where titles are mapped. So my question is, is there training data already publicly available out there or do I have to manually map ~20k job titles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [Job Title Classification Training Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12350/job-title-classification-training-data)